# Exponentiation with Matrices

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

How would exponentiation be done with matrices?

For example:

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\8&7\end{array}\right]^{\left[\begin{array}{cc}7&4\\2&9\end{array}\right]}$$

Where both base and exponent are matrices.

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\8&7\end{array}\right]^6$$

Where the base is a matrix, and the exponent is not.

$$6^{\left[\begin{array}{cc}7&4\\2&9\end{array}\right]}$$

Where the base is not, and the exponent is a matrix.

---

Wolfram Alpha [doesn't recognize it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B8,7%7D,%7B4,9%7D%7D%5E%7B%7B2,4%7D,%7B3,6%7D%7D), which makes me wonder if it is even possible.

Comment: The second case is clear, for the other cases it might help that $\exp(A)$ is defined as $$\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$$

Comment: interesting question. what about defining  $a^b$ as $e^{b \ln a}?$  you will need $a$ to be positive definite so that you can define $\ln a$ by the mclaurin series.

Answer (score 0):

Using [abel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9252/abel) and [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter)'s comments, I was able to solve my first question (matrix exponentiation with two matrices).

**Please let me know if I am incorrect in any of my logic.**

$$\text{Using a random example:}
\\
a = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\ 
8 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
\\
b = \begin{bmatrix}
7 & 4\\
2 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
\\
a^{b} = e^{b\ln(a)}
\\
\ln(a) = \begin{bmatrix}\ln(1)&\ln(2)\\\ln(8)&\ln(7)\end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
a^b = e^{\begin{bmatrix}7&4\\2&9\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\ln(1)&\ln(2)\\\ln(8)&\ln(7)\end{bmatrix}}
\\
a^b = \begin{bmatrix}
7 & 16\\
256 & 4782969
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Wolfram Alpha corroborates the final exponential arithmetic, $e^{\begin{bmatrix}7&4\\2&9\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}\ln(1)&\ln(2)\\\ln(8)&\ln(7)\end{bmatrix}}$, [link here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(%7B%7B1,2%7D,%7B8,7%7D%7D%20*%20ln(%7B%7B7,4%7D,%7B2,9%7D%7D))).

Comment: Yes, but ... $ln(A)$ is not the $ln$ of each component, and in general $B$ and $ln(A)$ do not commute so is it $e^{Bln(a)}$ or $e^{ln(A)B}$ ?

Comment: @GCab In the case of $e^{a\ln{b}}$ it is equivalent to $b^a$, **while** $e^{b\ln{a}}$ is equivalent to $a^b$. In my answer I use the [correct equivalence](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Eb+%3D+e%5E(bln(a))&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,+%22bln%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Variable%22%7D): $a^b=e^{b\ln{a}}$. At least this is my understanding, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @GCab As far as taking the log of a matrix, it is the same as taking the log of each number inside the matrix. [Wolfram Alpha corroborates this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(%7B%7B1,2%7D,%7B8,7%7D%7D)+%3D+%7B%7Bln(1),ln(2)%7D,%7Bln(8),ln(7)%7D%7D).

Answer (score 0):

- *Concerning the logarithm of a matrix*
  The logarithm (understood as the inverse of exp) of a matrix **is not** the log of each component:
  example
  $$
     \exp \left( {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}    0 & 0 & 0  \\    1 & 0
     & 0  \\    0 & 1 & 0  \\  \end{array} } \right)} \right) = \left(
     {\begin{array}{*{20}c}    0 & 0 & 0  \\    1 & 0 & 0  \\    {1/2} & 1
     & 0  \\  \end{array} } \right)\quad \quad \exp \left( {\left(
     {\begin{array}{*{20}c}    1 & 0 & 0  \\    1 & 1 & 0  \\    0 & 1 & 1
     \\  \end{array} } \right)} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}   
     e & 0 & 0  \\    e & e & 0  \\    {1/2e} & e & e  \\  \end{array} }
     \right)
     $$
  To my knowledge, it can instead be defined through the  Taylor
  expansion of $ln(\mathbf X)$ or better, of $ln(\mathbf I + (\mathbf X
   - \mathbf I))$ when this is convergent.
- *Concerning the matrices commutation*

  You shall be aware that the product of two Matrices $\mathbf A$ and
  $\mathbf B$, *in general* does not commute. Same for the product of 
  $ln(\mathbf A)$ and $\mathbf B$.
  You can *"define"* $\mathbf A
     ^{\mathbf B}$ as you like, as far as you state the **properties** you
  expect therefrom.

Comment: For my uses, Wolfram Alpha tells me that it is the same as taking the log of each number inside the matrix: [link here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7Bc,d%7D%7D+%3D+%7B%7Bloga,logb%7D,%7Blogc,logd%7D%7D). It is also the same as taking the $\exp$ of the matrix: [link here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7Bc,d%7D%7D+%3D+%7B%7Be%5Ea,e%5Eb%7D,%7Be%5Ec,e%5Ed%7D%7D). **You may still be correct, I am still a learning.**

Comment: well, it's comforting that you admit that you are still learning. And one thing you shall learn asap that an  **instrument**  shall be in your hands, and not vice versa: try and write "h^{{a,b},{c,d}} = {{h^a,h^b},{h^c,h^d}}" or "exp{{a,b},{c,d}} = {{exp(a),exp(b)},{exp(c),exp(d)}}" and see what you get.

Comment: Here is what I get for the [first case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=h%5E%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7Bc,d%7D%7D+%3D+%7B%7Bh%5Ea,h%5Eb%7D,%7Bh%5Ec,h%5Ed%7D%7D), and the [second case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7Bc,d%7D%7D+%3D+%7B%7Bexp(a),exp(b)%7D,%7Bexp(c),exp(d)%7D%7D). Both still return "True"

Comment: In fact, so what do you deduct from these?